# How do I show that $B$ has an infinite number of extreme points, but no faces (sides) of dimension $1$ or $2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $B = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$.

How do I show that $B$ has an infinite number of extreme points, but no faces (sides) of dimension $1$ or $2$ ?

I've been thinking about how to proceed. I know some theorems I could use if $B$ is a polyhedron, but this is not the case here ?

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote by $\partial B$ the boundary of $B$ : $\partial B=\lbrace (x,y,z)\in B | x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \rbrace$.

Any point $p=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ of $\partial B$ is an extreme point. Indeed,
let $P$ be the affine plane define by the equation
$x_px+y_py+z_py =1$. Then $B$ is wholly on one
side of $P$ (by Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$(x_px+y_py+z_py)^2 \leq  (x^2+y^2+z^2)(x_p^2+y_p^2+z_p^2)$ for
any other $(x,y,z)\in B$, so $|x_px+y_py+z_py| \leq 1$ and hence $x_px+y_py+z_py \leq 1$ ), and meets $P$ at $p$. This shows
that $p$ is indeed extremal.

Conversely, if $p=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ is not in $\partial B$ so that $\varepsilon=1-||p||>0$, then by the triangle inequality the open ball with center $p$ and radius $1-\varepsilon$ is contained in $B$. This shows that $p$ is in the interior of $B$, and so cannot be an extremal point.

The last two paragraphs thus show that the extremal points of $B$ are exactly the points on $\partial B$.

Remember that :

**Remark.** A face $F$ of $B$ (with $F\neq B$) consists only of extremal points of $B$.

Indeed, suppose  that a face $F$ of $B$ contains a nonextremal point $p$. By
  what we have just seen, $\varepsilon=1-||p||$ is $>0$. If $\overrightarrow{u}$
  is any vector with $||\overrightarrow{u}|| < \varepsilon$, then the two points
  $x_1=p-\overrightarrow{u}$ and $y_1=p+\overrightarrow{u}$ are in $B$, and 
  $p$ is strictly inside the line segment $[x_1y_1]$. Since $F$ is a face, 
  we deduce $x_1,y_1\in F$. 
  Next, if we put $x_2=-\frac{p}{||p||}$ and $y_2=\frac{p}{||p||}$, then $x_2,y_2$
  are in $B$, and $p$ is strictly inside the line segment $[x_2y_2]$. Since $F$ is a face, 
  we deduce $x_2,y_2\in F$. Since -$p\in [x_2y_2]$ and $F$ is convex, we see that
  $-p\in F$. Arguing as with $x_1$ and $y_1$, we see that
  $x_3=-p-\overrightarrow{u}$ and $y_3=-p+\overrightarrow{u}$ are in $F$. Next, since
  $\overrightarrow{u}$ is in the line segment $[y_1y_3]$ and $F$
  is convex, we see that $\overrightarrow{u}\in F$. Arguing as with
  $x_2$ and $y_2$, we see that $\frac{\overrightarrow{u}}{||\overrightarrow{u}||} \in F$,
  for any vector $\overrightarrow{u}$ whose norm is $< \varepsilon$. This shows
  that $\partial B \subseteq F$, hence $B \subseteq F$ by convexity. The remark is
  proved.

Let $F$ be a face of dimension $1$. Since the affine subspace spanned by $F$ is 
not reduced to a point, we need $F$ to contain at least two points, let us call 
them $p$ and $q$. Since $F$ is convex, we have $[pq] \subseteq F$. By the remark
above,  $[pq]$ contains only extremal points of $B$. So it is included in
$\partial B$, with $p=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$, $q=(x_q,y_q,z_q)$. Then the middle
point $r=(\frac{x_p+x_q}{2},\frac{y_p+y_q}{2},\frac{z_p+z_q}{2})$
must also lie in $\partial B$ : $||r||=1$. Using the parallelogram
identity $||p+q||^2+||p-q||^2=2(||p||^2+||q||^2)$, we see that
$||p-q||=0$, so $p=q$.

So there are no nontrivial one-dimensional faces. Obviously, we cannot have
two-dimensional faces either.

**Notes.** The "remark" above is in fact a very special case of a famous very general result, the [Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem). The fact the ball has no intermediate-dimensional faces is called [strict convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem)

Comment: "please describe the case of faces of dimension 1 and 2 in an introductory way with lots of details. " ? That's not the kind of request I satisfy because I don't do other people's homework for them, I only help.